# Can passwords in Artifactory's "storage.properties" file be encrypted?

Tags: artifactory

I'm working on setting up Artifactory and while it seems like a lot of external resource passwords can be encrypted from within the system, it appears that passwords to external RDBMS systems (MySQL, MS SQL Server, etc) remain in cleartext in the storage.properties file.  Can these be encrypted, or does that file itself need to be protected via the filesystem alone?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this JIRA issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6606?jql=text%20~%20%22encrypt%22). This feature will be released in the next Artifactory version. The issue also includes a working solution.